# Present ViewController that's larger than it's parent

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentation

So I have a custom `PresentationController` which means I've set `modalTransitioningStyle = .custom`. This means it's not set to `overCurrentContext` or `overFullscreen`. It also means that `definesPresentationContext` is not is not applicable, since it's only used in those cases.

With this I present a custom popover-like view controller that takes like third of the screen.

**Now the tricky part:**
On this custom presented VC, I want to present another view controller with the same custom presentation that is larger (let's say half of the screen) than the presenting one.

**Problem:**
The frame of the second presented view controller is constrained to the size and location of the parent, so you will not see it entirely.

Even if I would manage to present it on a fullscreen view controller behind the first, the content would also appear behind, not in front of it.

So the **question** is: How do I present a view controller that has larger bounds than the presenting one using my own Presentation Controller?

I don't think any code would help here, but let me know if you think otherwise.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @JacobCXDev and @ post owner where any of you guys able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem right now

Comment: @fphelp Ultimately, I ended up creating a new window and presenting the view controller on the window's rootViewController (see [here](https://github.com/jacobcxdev/Iris/blob/07c4a7206eef6210511e97374edbf62393a22df8/src/Objective-C/Controller/IrisTagCreationAlertCollectionViewController.x#L107-L124)).